# Start function not being called swftui

Tags: swift, function, swiftui

How can I start a function when opening a view in SWIFTUI?

When a view is displayed, I require that the first thing to do is run a function

Comment: Read the **very basics of SwiftUI** and do, for example, the tutorial at: https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/  there are many others. Hint `.onAppear{...}`

Comment: You can call it on `init` of whatever `class`/`struct`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are multiple ways.
You can either call your function inside the view via a `.onAppear`.

```
.onAppear {
    yourFunction()
}
```

Or by calling an initializer between the `class/struct` you have, and its `var body: Some View` as this:

```
struct YourView: View {
    init {
        yourFunction()
    }

    var body: some View {
        //Your view code...
    }
   }
```

I suggest reading the [Swift documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/) for a better understanding on these concepts.